# Easiest way to find filenames that differ by one word?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to write a python script that compares a list of filenames to itself, and pulls out any filenames that are exact matches, or differ by only one word...

Something along the lines of

```
def FindCloseMatches(list_in_question):
    match_list = []
    list_one = [{x: x.split()} for x in list_in_question]
    list_two = [{x: x.split()} for x in list_in_question]
    
    # pseudo-ish
    for x, y in zip(list_one, list_two):
        if x.values in list_one match all but one of y.values in list_two:
            match_list.append(x, y)
```

How would I go about comparing two lists of filenames, and finding any that differ by only one word or less?

For example, if I have a file named `WaterServiceLines.pdf` and `CustomerWaterServiceLines.pdf` (they are not all formatted the same way in terms of spaces and underscores etc.) then that would be a match. But `WaterServiceLines.pdf` and `SewerMainLines.pdf` would not be a match.

Comment: Define "easiest way".

Comment: Can you give us an example of a input and it's expected output?

Comment: That's already written in your Q. Please refrain from those "EDIT" sections btw. Your goal should be one coherent question. The editing history is available through SO, in case it becomes interesting. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, your description is vague, so please provide example input and output and elaborate why the output should be like that.

Comment: noted,  fixed that

Comment: @noah1400 see the edits i made :)

Comment: Do the words in the file names always start with capital letters?

Comment: For a start, write a function that returns whether two filenames match. Write a bunch of testcases (e.g. from the examples) to make sure it works as intended, even in corner cases. Then, use that function to find matching pairs in your input list. Lastly, when you have it working, take a critical look at the code to find out which parts could be simplified or optimized, because there's going to be a bunch of redundant calls. Only care for that _after_ you have it working correctly though.

Comment: @noah1400 yes, and now that i think about it, they all use spaces not underscores etc

Comment: how about `len( set(one_list_of_words) - set(othe_list_of_words) ) == 1` but this doesn't care if words are in the same order.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the matching pairs is where i start to lose you, entire filenames i get, but  then are you saying split the filenames into their individual words, and look for pairs?

Comment: better create some example data for test - and show expected results. It can show what you expect. For example what with `WaterServiceLines` and `LinesWaterCustomService` which are different by one word but they have words in different orders. I would say this problem is not easy task. Maybe could help standard module `difflib` which checks word by word.

Comment: Start with _something_. Maybe you can create a set of rules for the matching in plain human language first, then implement those rules in Python second. That first step makes it easier to structure your thoughts. Also, it can already be reviewed and discussed, and perhaps it will allow you to ask a concrete question, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

Assuming that all words are separated by Capital Letters

```py
import Levenshtein
import re
def FindCloseMatches(filenames):
    # remove file types from filenames
    filenames = [x.split('.')[0] for x in filenames]
    # split filenames into words
    for i in range(len(filenames)):
        filenames[i] = [s for s in re.split("([A-Z][^A-Z]*)", filenames[i]) if s != '']

    # compare each element in the list to itself
    # count the number of words that are different
    # if the number of words is 1 or less, then it is a match
    matches = []
    for i in range(len(filenames)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(filenames)):
            if Levenshtein.distance(filenames[i], filenames[j]) <= 1:
                # combin words into a string

                matches.append((''.join(filenames[i]), ''.join(filenames[j])))
    return matches

l = ['WaterServiceLines.pdf', 'CustomerWaterServiceLines.pdf', 'SewerMainLines.pdf', 'WaterServiceLines.pdf']

print(FindCloseMatches(l))
```

Output:

```
[('WaterServiceLines', 'CustomerWaterServiceLines'), ('WaterServiceLines', 'WaterServiceLines'), ('CustomerWaterServiceLines', 'WaterServiceLines')]
```

install levenshtein with `pip install levenshtein`

If you want the file types in your output:

```py
import Levenshtein
import re
def FindCloseMatches(filenames):
    # create dictionary keyed by filename, with value file type
    # e.g. {'WaterServiceLines': 'pdf', 'CustomerWaterServiceLines': 'pdf'}
    filetypes = {}
    for filename in filenames:
        filetypes[filename.split('.')[0]] = filename.split('.')[-1]

    filenames = [x.split('.')[0] for x in filenames]


    # split filenames into words
    for i in range(len(filenames)):
        filenames[i] = [s for s in re.split("([A-Z][^A-Z]*)", filenames[i]) if s != '']

    # compare each element in the list to itself
    # count the number of words that are different
    # if the number of words is 1 or less, then it is a match
    matches = []
    for i in range(len(filenames)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(filenames)):
            if Levenshtein.distance(filenames[i], filenames[j]) <= 1:
                # combine words into the filename and append the filetype
                f1 = ''.join(filenames[i])
                f2 = ''.join(filenames[j])
                f1 = f1 + '.' + filetypes[f1]
                f2 = f2 + '.' + filetypes[f2]
                matches.append((f1, f2))
    return matches

l = ['WaterServiceLines.pdf', 'CustomerWaterServiceLines.pdf', 'SewerMainLines.pdf', 'WaterServiceLines.pdf']

print(FindCloseMatches(l))
```

Output:

```
[('WaterServiceLines.pdf', 'CustomerWaterServiceLines.pdf'), ('WaterServiceLines.pdf', 'WaterServiceLines.pdf'), ('CustomerWaterServiceLines.pdf', 'WaterServiceLines.pdf')]
```

Comment: this is perfect, separation by space is exactly what i needed! thank you